# extending js.native class yields TypeError: Class constructor cannot be invoked without 'new'

Tags: scala.js

I get a TypeError when extending a `@js.native` class in scala.js and running in node.

```scala
object MainApp {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println(new B())
  }
}

class B extends A

@js.native
@JSImport("example", "A")
class A extends js.Object
```

Running complains about not calling `new`:

```
TypeError: Class constructor A cannot be invoked without 'new'
```

The generated code doesn't call `new` on the native parent class:

```
/** @constructor */
var $c_LB = (function $c_LB() {
    $i_$0040test$002dtest$002ftest.B.call(this)
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, Scala.js desugars classes into a "close enough" representation in ECMAScript 5.1 using `function`s and `prototype`s. This close enough desugaring is valid as long as you do not try to extend other ECMAScript `class`es (you can extend other `function`-based "classes").

If you need to extend a proper ES `class`, you need to tell Scala.js to emit ECMAScript 2015 `class`es as well. This can be done with the following sbt configuration:

```scala
// in a single-project build:
scalaJSLinkerConfig ~= { _.withESFeatures(_.withUseECMAScript2015(true)) }

// in a multi-project build:
lazy val myJSProject = project.
  ...
  settings(
    scalaJSLinkerConfig ~= { _.withESFeatures(_.withUseECMAScript2015(true)) }
  )
```